# How to parse string with regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have such string:

```
   string mystr = "webmaster@clantemplates.com|Action Required to Activate Membership for ClanTemplates|href=&quot;|&quot;>|6|6";
```

How to parse it to array of strings with "|" delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method; no need for a regex.

```
string[] parts = mystr.Split('|');
```

Comment: Sorry Luke, thought I was editing my answer, don't know what happened. Feel free to roll back.

Comment: I've followed my answer back through the post, don't know why it didn't go through. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use String.Split();

```
string mystr = "webmaster@clantemplates.com|Action Required to Activate Membership for ClanTemplates|href=&quot;|&quot;>|6|6";
string[] parts = mystr.Split(new char[] { '|' });
```

Comment: i get: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Look at my sample, i'm using `mystr.Split()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Regex, you need to remember to escape the `|` as `\|` in raw regex, and in C#, `"\\|"` or `@"\|"`.

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split (input, @"\|");
```

For something simple like this, just use `string[] parts = input.Split('|')`.  You shouldn't use regex in this case unless there's something special, like not wanting to split on escaped pipes (like `email@email.com|my value has a \| in it|more stuff'`).  In this example, you would use this:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split (input, @"(?<!\\)\|");
```